# How to upload files in postman which is a property in an object of array

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-upload, postman, rest

I am developing a REST API where I need to accept an array of objects. I have made a search and know how to upload a file with other parameters. Also I can send multiple files by adding them to body. But I need to send them as a property of an object and the API endpoint accepts an array of this object.

Let me explain it with an example

```
public class StaffInfo
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/staff/create")]
public void AddNewStaff(StaffInfo[] newStaff)
{
    :
    :
}
```

I want to test this endpoint and can't figure out how to send data with PostMan.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In Postman, you can pass the array of input as form-data. The format, for example passing the FirstName, would be: `newStaff[0].firstName`. For the Photo property, you can select the dropdown for the Key in Postman and change the type to File to set the file. Here's what it should look like in Postman:

[image]

When sending this, you can see the photo passed in the array in Visual Studio:

[image]